# Why didn't the inhibitor chip ever come up on a medical scan?

Tags: star-wars

Maybe Palpatine staged all medical examinations at the time of acceptance of the clone army, but later clones were pushed all over the galaxy in wars where they would get injured.

Why didn't a medical scan ever detect the inhibitor chip?

Was the inhibitor chip special in some way to evade detection? Is there anything about it in the canon?

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Inhibitor_chip - Organic. Which means they'd evade casual scans

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It did come up on a scan (in the Clone Wars episode *Conspiracy*), but it took a "Phase 5 atomic-level scan" scan to even see it, and that gave no specific clue to its function.

Even then, **it just looked like a small and relatively benign tumour**. It's worthy of note that this scan is described as being invasive and harmful to the individual, so it wouldn't usually be used on someone who was sick or injured, let alone someone who had died from a war inujry.

> **AZI:** *The scan is almost complete. Everything appears to be normal. Wait a second.*
>
> **Fives:** *What? What is it?*
>
> **AZI:** *It appears this clone has developed a tumor.*

Unfortunately for the Jedi, Palpatine made the evidence disappear at the end of the episode by having the biochip shipped to a medical facility on Coruscant which was under his control.